# Why is my month input being multiplied by ten?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a class that accepts user input for a month then outputs the number of days in said month. Whenever I test my class it doesn't give me an output for the number of days but instead just multiplies the month number by 10. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Appointment
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter a number that corresponds to a month: ");
       int month = kin.nextInt();
       System.out.print(month);
       int Days = 0;
       System.out.print(Days);
       if ( month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12)
       {
           Days = 31;
        }
        else if ( month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        {
            Days = 30;
        }
        else if ( month == 2)
        {
            Days = 28;
        }
    }
    public int getDays()
       {
           int Days = 0;
           return Days;
        }
     {


   } }
```

Comment: That code won't do what you are saying. `getDays()` is useless, and the local variable `Days` in your main function is only modified after printing the result.

Comment: Your month is not being multiplied by 10, but you are printing the month number, and then 0 immediately after without any line break. Also, you're printing the Days variable before changing it.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't multiply your month by `10`; you just printed a `0` immediately after the month.  The `print` method doesn't place anything after what you want to print, not even a newline.

```
Enter a number that corresponds to a month: 2
20
^^
| \
|  --- The `0` is from `Days`
------ The `2` is from `month`
```

Output a space or some other verbiage, or use `println` to output a newline after your output, to visually distinguish the two variables' output.

Also, print `Days` after you get it assigned properly, after all those `if` statements, so it's not `0` when it's printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you should use

System.out.println() instead of
System.out.print()

The problem is that you are printing first your month and then, inmediately after the number 0 (variable days) in the SAME Line.

Suggestion for next time, use a debugger :)

Answer (score 0):

You just print out month and then 0 without space. Also in your code your method getDays() never called. It full of mistakes.